# Xcode 9 swift 4 Dynamic reusable header for several viewController

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9, reusability, uicontainerview

I need 5 viewController all of them has the same header components. So I don't want to duplicate the same views and codes for each viewController.  I would like to create a header and use the header for each viewController. 
The problem is header will be filled by an object and this object has a list attribute. so i need to add this list attribute such a tableView. 
 [What one view controller look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WQBH.png)

I am trying to create an headerViewController and pass my object to it. And i will use this viewController in a container view for each 5 main view Controllers. But the height would be different so I can't define a height constraint to container view. in 5 view controller should use scroll view, because the total height will be higher than screen.

It is a little bit complicated because i try to solve this problem such a android developer :)

Comment: You can use UIContainer view. Create a main view controller and add the header to that, for the changing section use a container view and load the changing views there.

Comment: You can create a custom headerView subclassing UIView.Create custom XIB and provide an owner as this headerView. Add all the logic and creation of tableview in custom headerView class so that no duplication of code will b there and easy to reuse in other viewcontrollers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue creating a main view controller that contains a table view. And the common header is a type of tableviewcell. Then for each different body parts became another tableviewcell so according to type attribute of viewCOntroller, I am loading related tableviewCell. 
I did this after @midhun-mp comment. Thanks to him.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all items in `tableView` to be displayed all the time (no scrolling in `tableView`)

You should add height constraint to `tableView` or `containerView`

After loading/reloading the tableView with data set `tableViewHeightConstraint` OR `containerViewHeightConstraint` with content size height of `tableView`

```
tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
```

OR

```
containerViewHeightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
```